# View Stata variable labels in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stata

Stata `.dta` files include labels/descriptions for each column, which can be viewed in Stata using the `describe` command. For example, the `adults` and `kids` variables in [this online dataset](http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/stata/alcohol.dta), have descriptions `number of adults in household` and `number of children in household`, respectively:

```
clear
use http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/stata/alcohol.dta

describe

Contains data from http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/stata/alcohol.dta
  obs:         1,000                          
 vars:             4                          10 Nov 2007 11:33
 size:         5,000                          (_dta has notes)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
adults          byte    %8.0g                 number of adults in household
kids            byte    %8.0g                 number of children in household
income          int     %8.0g                 weekly income
consume         byte    %8.0g                 =1 if consume alcohol, =0 otherwise
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by:
```

Those descriptions do not show up in Pandas, for example with `describe()`:

```
df = pd.read_stata('http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/stata/alcohol.dta')
df

     adults  kids  income  consume
0         2     2     758        1
1         2     3    1785        1
2         3     0    1200        1
..      ...   ...     ...      ...
997       2     0    1383        1
998       2     2     816        0
999       2     2     387        0

df.describe()

            adults         kids       income      consume
count  1000.000000  1000.000000  1000.000000  1000.000000
mean      2.012000     0.722000   649.528000     0.766000
std       0.815181     1.078833   460.657826     0.423584
min       1.000000     0.000000    12.000000     0.000000
25%       2.000000     0.000000   295.000000     1.000000
50%       2.000000     0.000000   562.500000     1.000000
75%       2.000000     1.000000   887.500000     1.000000
max       6.000000     5.000000  3846.000000     1.000000
```

Is there a way to view this information after loading it to a Pandas DataFrame using `read_stata()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Stata's toy dataset `auto` as an example:

```
sysuse auto, clear

describe

Contains data from auto.dta
  obs:            74                          1978 Automobile Data
 vars:            12                          13 Apr 2014 17:45
 size:         3,182                          (_dta has notes)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
make            str18   %-18s                 Make and Model
price           int     %8.0gc                Price
mpg             int     %8.0g                 Mileage (mpg)
rep78           int     %8.0g                 Repair Record 1978
headroom        float   %6.1f                 Headroom (in.)
trunk           int     %8.0g                 Trunk space (cu. ft.)
weight          int     %8.0gc                Weight (lbs.)
length          int     %8.0g                 Length (in.)
turn            int     %8.0g                 Turn Circle (ft.)
displacement    int     %8.0g                 Displacement (cu. in.)
gear_ratio      float   %6.2f                 Gear Ratio
foreign         byte    %8.0g      origin     Car type
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by: foreign
```

The following works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_stata('auto.dta', iterator = True)
labels = data.variable_labels()
labels

Out[5]: 
{'make': 'Make and Model',
 'price': 'Price',
 'mpg': 'Mileage (mpg)',
 'rep78': 'Repair Record 1978',
 'headroom': 'Headroom (in.)',
 'trunk': 'Trunk space (cu. ft.)',
 'weight': 'Weight (lbs.)',
 'length': 'Length (in.)',
 'turn': 'Turn Circle (ft.) ',
 'displacement': 'Displacement (cu. in.)',
 'gear_ratio': 'Gear Ratio',
 'foreign': 'Car type'}
```

Comment: so how to add a variable label to a DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

#### Edited:

OK If I understand you correctly, you are looking for frequency counts?
If so, `.value_counts()` should do the trick.

```
df = pd.read_stata("http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/stata/alcohol.dta")

adults_values = df.adults.value_counts().sort_index().to_frame()
print(adults_values)

   adults
1     247
2     562
3     133
4      49
5       8
6       1
```

```
kids_values = df.kids.value_counts().sort_index()
print(kids_values)

   kids
0   626
1   133
2   158
3    61
4    20
5     2
```

**Variable Descriptions**

[`.info()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) gives you information on the datatypes of variables in each column.(`int8`, `int64`, etc)

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1000 entries, 0 to 999
Data columns (total 4 columns):
adults     1000 non-null int8
kids       1000 non-null int8
income     1000 non-null int16
consume    1000 non-null int8
dtypes: int16(1), int8(3)
memory usage: 12.7 KB
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for the variable descriptions which don't show up in these functions. I clarified the question using your dataset as an example.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "variable descriptions" ? There are ways to get pretty detailed information about variables with `pandas`, but it'll most likely be different than what you're used to with Stata

Comment: The text "number of adults in household"